# Agregar Evento Click a un Boton Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Creo un Boton desde codigo c# , ahora nesecito agregar un metodo cuando se haga click en el...hize esto pero no funciona

```
public void AgregarBoton()
        {
            Button miBoton = new Button();
            miBoton.ID = "BtnCheck";
            miBoton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
            miBoton.Font.Size = 9;
            miBoton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Indigo;
            miBoton.Text = "CHECKOUT";
            miBoton.Click += new System.EventHandler(MiBoton_Click);
            miBoton.Width = 120;
            miBoton.Height = 30;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(miBoton);
        }
        public void MiBoton_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = (Button)sender;
            Session["p"] = "fsdfsdfsf";
            Label2.Text = Session["p"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Quizás el problema es que también lo estás creando en postback

Comment: en tal caso q deberia hacer, por que mi evento Load esta vacio?????

Comment: ejecuto el metodo AgregarBoton() desde otro boton

Comment: alli tienes el problema, al darse el evento pierdes la asignacion, no puedes crear controles dinamicos desde los eventos de otros coontroles, debes hacerlo dentro del Init o load unicamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberias analiza este articulo

[Cómo: Crear dinámicamente controles en ASP.NET utilizando .NET Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/317794)

veras que al crear controles dinamicos debes ubicar este en los eventos Init o Load y en cada post debes asignar el evento ya que sino lo haces este pierde la asignacion y por consiguiente no se lanzara el eventos.

La verdad es que si puedes evita crear controles de esta foma, usa el `Repeater`

[Cómo: Agregar un control Repeater a una página de formularios Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/zzx23804(v=vs.80).aspx)

si necesitas crear un template dinamico que se genere segun los datos que asignes

Comment: me gusta tu sugerencia..pero la verdad ya esta programado de esa forma y si logro que funcione el boton queda ..tendre en cuenta el repeater para otra oportunidad

Comment: claro pero el tema es que de la forma que esta programado el evento no te funcionara, debes poner la creacion del control en el Load o Init

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class Carro : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         private Button miBoton = new Button();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                    miBoton.Click += new System.EventHandler(MiBoton_Click); 
            }

        }
public void AgregarBoton()
        {

            miBoton.ID = "BtnCheck";
            miBoton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
            miBoton.Font.Size = 9;
            miBoton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Indigo;
            miBoton.Text = "CHECKOUT";
            miBoton.Click += new System.EventHandler(MiBoton_Click);
            miBoton.Width = 120;
            miBoton.Height = 30;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(miBoton);
        }
        public void MiBoton_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = (Button)sender;
            Session["p"] = "fsdfsdfsf";
            Label2.Text = Session["p"].ToString();
        }
}
```